# How to create mouse cursor pointer?

Tags: website-design, icon, gif, cur

I wanted to use different funny mouse cursor pointer to my commercial website project. Is there any website providing this mouse pointer images for free or for low price?

If not how can i create a mouse cursor images myself. I guess its extension is .cur

I have little knowledge of photoshop and gimp tool. Can i create the mouse cursor pointers with this?
If you can give a link to free cursor pointer images or tutorials to create this mouse cursor pointer, it will be much helpful to me. Let me know where should i start first.

Thanks

Comment: There's also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144836/css-cursor-customization

Answer (score 0):

**Finding cursors**
I'm sure that a simple search could pull up [many free cursor sites](https://www.google.com/#q=free+mouse+cursors). The first site in the linked result, Open Cursor Library, seems fairly extensive to me. I'm sure that you should have little trouble if what you want is to use cursors.

**Creating cursors**
If you want to design your own cursors instead, you could surely open Photoshop or Gimp and create a cursor file. I don't know either very well, but if they don't export/save cursor files, there are surely plugins for it.

Even better, you could just use Gimp, Photoshop, or an [online image converter](http://www.digitalcoding.com/tools/image-converter.html) to convert your images to cursor formats. This allows you to use whatever software you are most comfortable with to design your cursors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I too searched for free mouse pointer images, but i'm not sure about the license all sites having. That is the reason i posted a question. So that i can get a link if someone who is good in graphic field can redirect me to a free commercial use website. Because they might have already used this kinds in their projects.